# Discrepancy in two-point correlator integral of Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, integration, complex-numbers, propagator

The two point correlator of Quantum H.O. of natural frequency $\omega$, calculated using path integrals, is
$$C_{2}=D\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right) \propto \int \frac{d w^{\prime}}{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-i w^{\prime}\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)}}{w^{\prime2}-w^{2}}\tag{1}$$

which evaluated using contour integral in complex plane, comes out to be (can be verified by conventionally calculating it using ladder operators) -
$$C_{2}\propto-ie^{-iw|t_2-t_1|}\tag{2}$$

But $(1)$ is purely real as can be seen by decomposing exp. into sines and cosines -
$$ \int \frac{d w^{\prime}}{2 \pi} \frac{cos(w^{\prime}\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right))}{w^{\prime2}-w^{2}}-i\int \frac{d w^{\prime}}{2 \pi} \frac{sin( w^{\prime}\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right))}{w^{\prime2}-w^{2}}\tag{3} $$

second term is an odd function therefore vanishes.

Why is there a discrepancy between $(1)$ and $(2)$?

---

$\bf{Edit1}$ : Another potential source of same doubt is Griffiths' INTRODUCTION TO QUANTUM MECHANICS, first ed., eq. $\bf{(11.50)}$ reads
$$G(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{2}} \frac{2}{r} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{s \sin (s r)}{k^{2}-s^{2}} d s=\frac{1}{4 \pi^{2} r} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{s \sin (s r)}{k^{2}-s^{2}} d s\tag{11.50}$$
which is simplified version of $(1)$ in $3$D ($\omega'$ renamed as $s$ and $\omega$ as $k$). This is purely real.

He then evaluates it with contour integrals to (eq$\bf{(11.55)}$) -
$$G(\mathbf{r})=\frac{i}{8 \pi^{2} r}\left[\left(i \pi e^{i k r}\right)-\left(-i \pi e^{i k r}\right)\right]=-\frac{e^{i k r}}{4 \pi r}$$
which is not a real number.

Also, [this](https://physicspages.com/pdf/Griffiths%20QM/Griffiths%20Problems%2011.16.pdf) may be helpful.

$\bf{Edit2}$ : Doing the integral $(1)$ using two different contours -

$\bf{1.}$With the following
[image]

for $t_2-t_1>0$ and the limit the radius of small semicircles goes to zero,
I got
$$C_2=\frac{sin(\omega x)}{2\omega}\tag{4}$$
(Note that the contributions from small semicircles do not vanish under the limit radius$\rightarrow 0$)

$\bf{2.}$Taking contour with shifted poles -
[image]

I got
$$C_2=-i \frac{e^{-i \omega x}}{2 \omega}\tag{5}$$

I know that using different contours to regulate the integral gives different results. But here's what I'm thinking - It is obviously an improper integral hence we can only assign principle value to it. Also, both terms in $(3)$ diverges but second term's integrand is an odd function. So, divergence in $\omega'>0$ region would exactly cancel the divergence in $\omega'<0$ region. There, $(1)$ is divergent (not "exactly" divergent, but is of the indeterminate form $\infty$-$\infty$) but still lies on real axis.

So I'm thinking, also inpired by comments, that deforming contour or shifting the poles would render the second term in $(3)$ not exactly an odd function. But consider the second contour, we shift $\omega \rightarrow \omega-i\epsilon$, carry out the integration and take limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+} $. **In this limit, shouldn't the result converge to a real number?**

Also, **Why we choose contour $\bf{2}$ and not $\bf{1}$ to calculate $\bf{C_2}$ of H.O.?**

Comment: What contour are you using in he complex plane?  Does it respect the $t\to -t$ symmetry needed for the integral to be real?

Comment: General tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).